# Is there an equivalent for afconvert for video on the Macintosh?

Tags: ios, macos, video-encoding, h.264

afconvert can be used for audio conversions for iPhone / iPad

but what should be used for video conversions/ transcoding?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg is probably the way to go (command-line):
http://www.ffmpeg.org/

Great GUI alternative:
http://handbrake.fr/

Comment: Yes, I ended up using handbrake. Its free, GUI, and ability to queue batch operations is pretty handy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would typically Quicktime Pro with the "iPhone" export preset. That generates a 480x320 full screen H.264 video that can also contain audio. This file will then play on an iPhone or iPad with no problems.